# regex issue with non printable chars

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that returns one or more matches from a string and it's driving me nuts.

```
(?<=\x03).*?(?=\r)
```

The above should be looking for a start char of ETX (Char 3) and an end char of Carriage return.

I want the text between each start and end char "block".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you using the regex? What tells you it does not work? Are you using it in some programming code or in some editor? Also, please post some text to test against.

Comment: The regex does what you say. But, what do you mean by start and end `block`? There is `SOH, STX, ETX, EOT` control codes. Maybe you need `(?<=\x03).*?(?=\x04)`

Comment: I want the text only between ascii char 3 and ascii char 13.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ignore me it does work.  Think I was getting confused during debugging an the matches attribute looking to be zero. A small test proves it is ok (in VB).

```
    Dim TestString1 As String = Chr(3) & "Some Text to Extract 1" & Chr(13)
    Dim TestString2 As String = Chr(3) & "Some Text to Extract 2" & Chr(13)
    Dim TestString3 As String = Chr(3) & "Some Text to Extract 3" & Chr(13)

    Dim TestString As String = TestString1 & " random noise " & TestString2 & " more random noise " & TestString3
    Dim Matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(TestString, "(?<=\x03).*?(?=\r)")

    Dim Index As Integer = 0
    Dim result As New StringBuilder
    result.Append("No of Matches found = " & Matches.Count & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
    For Each m As Match In Matches
        Index += 1
        result.Append(Index & ": " & m.Groups(0).Value & vbCrLf)
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString())
```